# HTML5 Parser/wrapper

Tags: html

It may be the very elementary question. But I would like to know,

is there any HTML5 parser/application available which will allow me to play/execute HTML file without the need of any browser.

I am having a web-page with HTML5 tags, which I am executing with standard browser like Firefox, chrome, opera. Though this browsers are rich and powerful, my intention for mentioned browsers is to just execute the HTML page.

So instead of installing full-fledged browser (or any lightweight browser), is there any wrapper/parser available to render the HTML5 page ? If possible, which can use either blink/gecko layout engine.

**Note**: This HTML5 page is used to play audio/video/images
Also, I am preferring "blink engine"

Comment: Tell us what you are trying to do, what features are needed? What are not?

Comment: @richard, I was trying to use lightweight browsers so far. But I think they don't fit into bill. I am new to this terminology/technology. Basically, I want only rendering features of engine and capability to load pages from HTTP/HTTPS/FTP protocol

Comment: And what features do you not want?

Comment: “I want only rendering features of engine and capability to load pages from HTTP/HTTPS/FTP protocol” — so you want… a browser? I don't understand what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a headless browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to "execute"  a page with all the capabilities of the Webkit engine. Or use the [Firefox SDK](https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/) to execute a headless Firefox.